# Bootstrap Columns Not Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can't figure out why the columns aren't being structured with this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">  
                <a href="">About</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="image.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"> 
                <a href="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal">SHARE</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included the BS CSS? :-) In other news, I don't know BS but in Foundation you can't nest `.columns` inside `.columns` - you have to put them inside another `.row`

Comment: would you post the "header" of your HTML File?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/52j6avkb/

Comment: @Joe is correct; nesting columns in Bootstrap requires an additional `.row`

Comment: It works just fine: http://www.bootply.com/Xq5UWsNCw2. Just make sure that you test with  the appropriate screen size.

Comment: What is the need for `col-md-12` without another row?

Comment: why is there a col-12 around this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/IAq8t3KYUN)

```
<div class="container-fluid"> <!-- If Needed Left and Right Padding in 'md' and 'lg' screen means use container class -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <img src="image.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <a href="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal">SHARE</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 16):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">  
                    <a href="">About</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="image.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <a href="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal">SHARE</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to nest the interior columns inside of a row rather than just another column. It offsets the padding caused by the column with negative margins.

A simpler way would be

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">  
          <a href="">About</a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="image.png">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4"> 
           <a href="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal">SHARE</a>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to have one single row, with 3 columns.

Comment: See updated edit. The nest is only necessary (original example) if you wanted to increase your padding.

Comment: OP's code works fine "as is": http://www.bootply.com/Xq5UWsNCw2 You do **not** need another `row` to complete this task.

Comment: @PM77-1 Working fine and following the correct protocol based on framework docs are two separate things. Yea you can get away with it, but Bootstrap says "To nest your content with the default grid, add a new .row and set of * columns within an existing column." Besides the fact, the code needed to be simplified (not nested). And, there is the issue of padding creating horizontal scrollbars which can't always be resolved without a row.

Comment: @PM77-1 it works, but I can't duplicate it outside of the simulator.

Comment: Are you sure your window size is big enough for them to properly display? Kind of an obvious thing, but with md instead of sm, it could happen :)

Comment: One more time: test with appropriate screen sizes (browser window sizes). Your logic starts from `medium` sizes and up.  `sm` and `xs` will still show stacked elements.

Answer (score 4):

Your Nesting DIV structure was missing, you must add another ".row" div when creating nested divs in bootstrap :

Here is the Code:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4"> <a href="">About</a>
    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="https://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100px" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"> <a href="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal">SHARE</a>
    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

### Refer the Bootstrap example description for the same:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

## Nesting columns

To nest your content with the default grid, add a new .row and set of .col-sm-* columns within an existing .col-sm-* column. Nested rows should include a set of columns that add up to 12 or less (it is not required that you use all 12 available columns).

---

### Here is the working Fiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/52j6avkb/1/embedded/result/

Comment: It needs to be 3 columns, one row, as stated above.

Comment: Are you talking about the code? If you were reffering the second code in my answer so as I mentioned it was the sample from Bootstrap.. just to explain the "Nesting". Or else please elaborate a little more what exactly you mean by "3 columns, one row"

Comment: Whoever Downvoted the anwser, can you please mention the reason for  downvote?

Comment: I gave you +1 because your answer actually does work. There is no reason to downvote this. It's a different implementation with a container div.

Answer (score 3):

While this does not address the OP's question, I had trouble with my bootstrap rows / columns while trying to use them **in conjunction with Kendo** ListView (even with the bootstrap-kendo css).

Adding the following css fixed the problem for me:

```
#myListView.k-widget, #catalog-items.k-widget * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that those classes are present in the CSS?
Are you using twitter-bootstrap-rails gem?
It still uses Bootstrap 2.X version and those are Bootstrap 3.X classes. The CSS grid changed since.

You can switch to the bootstrap3 branch of the gem https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/bootstrap3 or include boostrap in an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have linked the CDN link.

//Latest version v5

```
    <div class="col-md-12"> // This line is optional.
      
    <div class="col-md-4">  // Start from here.
            <a href="">About</a>
        </div>
```